# GoogleMap returning both null and not null in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have the following class called **GoogleMapController** that initializes a `GoogleMap` and plots `markers` on defined locations.

**GoogleMapController.java**

```
class GoogleMapController {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = GoogleMapController.class.getSimpleName();

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;



    void initGoogleMap(final Activity activity, final int frameResID) {


                MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(frameResID,mapFragment).commit();

                mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"INIT==>"+String.valueOf(googleMap));
                        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
                    }
                });
    }

    void putLocationWithMarker(
            final Activity activity,
            final LatLng latLng,
            final String tag,
            final String title,
            final int markerResource) {



        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"LOC ==>"+String.valueOf(mGoogleMap));

                if (mGoogleMap != null) {
                    mGoogleMap.addMarker(
                            new MarkerOptions()
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(markerResource))
                                    .title(title)
                                    .position(latLng))
                            .setTag(tag);

                    if (mUserLatLng != null) {
                        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mUserLatLng,15));
                    }
                }
                else
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Google Map is NULL");
    }

}
```

I also have another class called **GMapJSInterface** that exposes the features to perform operations on the map to an external user

**GMapJSInterface**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class GMapJSInterface {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = GMapJSInterface.class.getSimpleName();

    private Activity mActivity;
    private GoogleMapController mGoogleMapController;

    public GMapJSInterface(final Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mGoogleMapController = new GoogleMapController();

    }

   // @JavascriptInterface
    public void initGoogleMap(final String mapFrameIDStr) {

        if (mActivity != null) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mapFrameIDStr)) {

                final int mapFrameIDint = Integer.parseInt(mapFrameIDStr);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Frame ID: " + mapFrameIDint);


                        mGoogleMapController.initGoogleMap(mActivity, mapFrameIDint);


            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error: EMPTY FRAME ID!!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error: ACTIVITY NULL!");
        }
    }

    public void putLocations(final String locations) {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,locations);

        try {
            final JSONArray locationArray = new JSONArray(locations);

            Log.d(LOG_TAG,String.valueOf(locationArray));
            for (int i = 0; i < locationArray.length(); i++) {
                final JSONObject location = locationArray.getJSONObject(i);

                final Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(location.getString("lat"));
                final Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(location.getString("lng"));
                final String tag = location.getString("tag");
                final String title = location.getString("title");

                final int resID = Integer.parseInt(location.getString("markerID"));

                mGoogleMapController.putLocationWithMarker(
                        mActivity,
                        new LatLng(latitude,longitude),
                        tag,title,resID);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

In my **MainActivity.java**, I'm simply doing the following: -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GMapJSInterface gMapJSInterface = new GMapJSInterface(this);

        gMapJSInterface.initGoogleMap(String.valueOf(R.id.map_frame));

        final String locationArray =

        "[ \n " +
                "{ \"lat\" : \"12\", \n" +
                "  \"lng\" : \"12\", \n" +
                "  \"tag\" : \"0\", \n" +
                "  \"title\" : \"BLORE\", \n" +
                "  \"markerID\" : \""+String.valueOf(R.drawable.l_marker)+"\"\n" +
                "} \n" +
         "]";



        gMapJSInterface.putLocations(locationArray);

    }
}
```

The problem here is:

1. When I call the `initGoogleMap` method of the GMapInterface class, I do get a map opened in my frame in Android and I get the following in my logcat

`11-25 14:50:31.590 5831-5831/? D/GoogleMapController: INIT==>com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap@1b9e89d4`

2. When I call the `putLocations` on the same class, my logcat shows the following: -

`11-25 14:50:30.850 5831-5831/? D/GoogleMapController: LOC ==>null
11-25 14:50:30.850 5831-5831/? E/GoogleMapController: Google Map is NULL`

I don't understand how I can have the same object as null and not null.

Comment: It's multithreading ... http://ideone.com/PPHi95

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you doing this in the `onMapReady(GoogleMap map)` callback instead? At that point the map should not be null.

It looks like you're trying to synchronously set up the map and then put locations into it - sometimes it could be ready by the time you call `putLocations`, sometimes it won't be.

Best thing to do, as far as I'm aware, is to call `getMapAsync` and set locations or grab a reference to the map while in `onMapReady`, these maps can have a noticeable memory impact at the best of times, so use callbacks!

Comment: But my requirement is to put locations from outside whenever wanted. I understand the fact that both the executions are happening at the same time, which is why for one it's null and for the other it isn't. How do I resolve this without putting the locations in `onMapReady`?

Comment: Btw, I AM holding a reference to the map in `onMapReady`?

Comment: You have to do it in onMapReady realistically. I don't understand though - can you post more code or elaborate on your requirement? What I'm wondering is why do you want to be able to put objects into the map even when it's null? That's a scary requirement!